# python - "global name is not defined"

Tags: python

2 days ago I downloaded Pythonista for iOs. Now I do my first steps with python.
I just tried now to seperate a Class in a file. But now it shows up the error: global name is not defined. Why? Thank you!

The 2 Files:
the main.py

```
from PersonClass import Person

peter = Person("peter", 17)
firstname = peter.getName()
print (firstname)
```

and the PersonClass.py

```
class Person(object):   
     def __init__(self, name, alter):
        self.__alter = alter
        self.__name = name

     def alterBekommen(self):
        return self.__alter

     def getName(self):
        return self.__name

     def setName(newName):
        self.__name = newName
```

Comment: Works fine for me, i tried python2.7 and python3

Comment: Also don't use names starting with __

Comment: Can you copy and paste your exact error message - which line does it generate an error.